# How would the input value be printed to the table?

Tags: javascript, html

i want the input value to be printed on the right corner under the table with id="realuchat", but the following code won't work. i tried to use  by adding it as a new element with js but it went wrong. kindly help me with it.

```js
function xyz(){
 var a = document.getElementById("chat");
 a.placeholder="   ";
 a.addEventListener("mouseout",gh);
 function gh(){
  a.placeholder="Type a message...";
 }
 a.addEventListener("keyup",jh);
 function jh(){
  preventDefault();
  if(keycode === 13){
   document.getElementById("sub").click();
  }
 }
}
function talk(){
 var htalk = document.getElementById("realhchat");
 var utalk = document.getElementById("realuchat");
 var talk= document.getElementById("chat").value;
 var elh = document.createElement("td");
 var elu = document.createElement("td");
 var diau = document.createTextNode(talk);
 var table = document.getElementById("realuchat");
 table.appendChild(td);
}
```

```html
<div id="mlink" align="right" style="padding-top:5px;">
 <a href="daju.html" class="mlink">Home</a>
 <a href="wallpaper.html" class="mlink" style="padding-left:18px">Wallpapers</a>
</div>
<div class="header" align="center"><p class="websitename">daju.in</p></div>
<div id="daju" align="left">
<p><img src="heavren.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="padding-right:8px;"/>
<table id="fakechat" border="0" cellpadding="2px"  bgcolor="blue"><tr><td>Hey what"s up? Welcome to Daju.in.Let's start to talk.</td></tr></table></p></div> 
<div align="left"><table border="0" cellpadding="2px" id="realhchat" bgcolor="#4c68d7"></table>
<div align="right"><table border="0" cellpadding="2px" id="realuchat" bgcolor="#bc2a8d"></table>
<div id="chatroom" style="padding-top:20px;">
 <form align="center">
  <input onmouseover="xyz()" id="chat" type="text" placeholder="Type a message..."/>
  <input id="sub" onsubmit="talk()" type="submit" value="Send"/>
 </form><p id="l"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Creating event listeners inside other event handlers is a really bad practice...especially if you don't understand the implications. Move all the `addEventListener` code out of `xyz()` and put that inside a page load event listener. Also poor practice to mix inline event listeners and external ones. Stick to one approach or the other and lean towards using external ones

Comment: Can you please explain that in detail. I am still a bit confused.because xyz() was running properly. but as soon as i created talk() function the problem took root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your major errors - you will tweak the code further if you like:

```js
function xyz(){
 var a = document.getElementById("chat");
 a.placeholder="   ";
 a.addEventListener("mouseout",gh);
 function gh(){
  a.placeholder="Type a message...";
 }
 a.addEventListener("keyup",jh);
 function jh(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  if(evt.keycode === 13){
   document.getElementById("sub").click();
  }
 }
}
function talk(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
 var htalk = document.getElementById("realhchat");
 var utalk = document.getElementById("realuchat");
 var talk= document.getElementById("chat").value;
 var elh = document.createElement("tr");
 var elu = document.createElement("td");
 var diau = document.createTextNode(talk);
 var table = document.getElementById("realuchat");
    diau.innerHTML = talk;
    elu.appendChild(diau);
    elh.appendChild(elu);
 table.appendChild(elh);
}
```

```html
<div id="mlink" align="right" style="padding-top:5px;">
 <a href="daju.html" class="mlink">Home</a>
 <a href="wallpaper.html" class="mlink" style="padding-left:18px">Wallpapers</a>
</div>
<div class="header" align="center"><p class="websitename">daju.in</p></div>
<div id="daju" align="left">
<p><img src="heavren.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="padding-right:8px;"/>
<table id="fakechat" border="0" cellpadding="2px"  bgcolor="blue"><tr><td>Hey what"s up? Welcome to Daju.in.Let's start to talk.</td></tr></table></p></div> 
<div align="left"><table border="0" cellpadding="2px" id="realhchat" bgcolor="#4c68d7"></table>
<div align="right"><table border="0" cellpadding="2px" id="realuchat" bgcolor="#bc2a8d"></table>
<div id="chatroom" style="padding-top:20px;">
 <form align="center" onsubmit="talk(event)" >
  <input onmouseover="xyz()" id="chat" type="text" placeholder="Type a message..."/>
  <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Send"/>
 </form><p id="l"></p>
</div>
```